# Is there a difference between running the source command from the mysql command line client and '<' from outside it? if so, when should I use each?

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7, command-line

I can run the following commands:

```
C:\myfolder>mysql -uuser -ppassword
```

Then from within the client do:

```
mysql>source C:\path\to\file.sql
```

Or I can do:

```
C:\myfolder>mysql -uuser -ppassword  < C:\path\to\file.sql
```

Is there a difference between these two commands? if so, what is it and when should I use each?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are the same, but you can use only one depending in which environment you are.

for example when you are in **DOS/ linux prompt** you can only run *mysql.exe*

in **Mysql command**  mode you only can use *source*.

so there is **no need to change** the environments to import the sql file.